# Measuring properties of Van Allen radiation belts

Tags: probe, radiation, van-allen-belt

How are the properties of the Van Allen radiation belts measured or monitored?

Below is the link of my question, that leads me to asking this one. One method is mentioned there but there may be others.

[Analyzing Van Allen belt's radiation Dataset](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/54822/12102)

Comment: Can you narrow down the question a bit?  There are tons of things that are measured.  Are you asking about something in particular?

Comment: I was asking for radiation data, now I found on on https://www.kaggle.com/